# Using a .sql file in Database manipulation with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I am kinda new to the whole development side, but I want to be good.

In database creation, I used to do this via PHPMyAdmin --> Wamp Server.

I got to learn how to use MySQL Workbench, and I am liking the experience.

The problem is, when I have the .sql file created via use of Work Bench, e.g. data.sql, I cannot import it to PHPMyAdmin, so as to continue in a my developments (web-related) as there are many errors comming up e.g. #1146.

It is really frustrating since I have to do double work and create what I did in Work Bench in PHP MyAdmin.

Is there a simpler way?

Like can I just connect to a .sql file (as the database) and continue with execution of my projects? (Its a bit stupid, but I have been reduced to that.)

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there are errors in the generated script then your model is errorenous. You can try it locally first in the SQL section to see what's wrong before you feed it to PMA.

Comment: i dont get that part:  "I have to do double work"? if you use same database in Workbench and phpmyadmin then database changes will be visible also in phpmyadmin.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic Where does Paul explicitly say they're using the same database?

Are the database the same, and you're using two different means of accessing it? Or, are the databases different and you're simply trying to "clone" one database to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post seems like it might help you out, did you check the default encoding of the dump and make sure mysql expects the right type of encoding?

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,275798,275798

Also: Please read the policies of the board before asking your question.  It states to do some research before asking questions like this... I googled "mysql workbench dump to phpmyadmin" and the very first item that popped up was a [**video**](http://www.screenr.com/vtps) explaining this EXACT situation.  :)